# Approving and improving edit suggestions

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

How come when I click "Improve" on an edit suggestion the approval is passed on to the Community user?

Comment: Technically, you didn't quite approve it since you had to do other stuff to the post before committing an edit... but I'd like to here what the powers-that-be were thinking when they implemented this.

Comment: Hold'on, if you actually typed something to improve it, I thought the system would make the edit yours?

Comment: @Willie, the last edit is mine. However the suggested edit gets approved automatically by Community.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that the edit is approved by community, or do you mean that the edit is shown as being done by community?

Comment: Approved by. It shows as suggested by the user suggesting it. Then an additional edit by me.

Comment: @Willie: I think Asaf has [this deleted question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/61155/revisions) in mind. Jodles and Asaf edited simultaneously on 11:39:46. While the page of the suggested edit doesn't exist anymore, you can see on the [suggested edit stats](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits) that Jodles's edit was approved by the community user.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks, Detective. :-)

Comment: I like @J.M.'s interpretation: you didn't quite approve it. But I assume that if no-one approves or rejects the edit, the edit will stay in the queue.

Comment: Please, add [tag:suggested-edits] to the question; ironically, suggestions are disabled *here.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approval is shown as coming from Community as a means of quickly identifying that it was an "Improve" action rather than a standard "Approve" action. This has slightly less of an impact here, since only one approver is necessary. Elsewhere, it's basically "Community is approving the edit so that you can step in yourself", which I see J.M. illustrated nicely in the comments above.

However, it remains useful because [this makes it an explicit scenario to track](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80518/improved-edit-suggestions-approved-by-community/80550#80550). By having the approver be Community, one can instantly observe what edits are getting Improved, rather than what is getting straight-up Approved.

The person responsible for the Improve action is also readily available, as it will always be the user whose edit comes immediately after the Improved Suggested Edit.

Comment: I see. Thanks. In this case you may heavily want to consider MathJax in the suggestion review page. Most of the $\LaTeX$ suggestions get automatically approved and only then reviewed.

Comment: @Asaf You mean [esto](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/reviewing-suggested-edits)? I'll see if I can get another look into that.

Comment: Yes. I mean that issue.